# Having trouble parsing a complex JSON file

Tags: c#, .net, json, parsing

I am developing an app that uses Microsoft's Xbox Music API. When doing a search query, I get a JSON string describing available albums, artists and songs which looks like this:

```
{
"Artists": {
    "Items": [{
        "Genres": ["Electronic / Dance"],
        "Subgenres": ["Breakbeat / Electro"],
        "Id": "music.7AF41000-0200-11DB-89CA-0019B92A3933",
        "Name": "Hybrid Theory",
        "ImageUrl": "http://musicimage.xboxlive.com/content/music.7AF41000-0200-11DB-89CA-0019B92A3933/image?locale=en-US",
        "Link": "http://music.xbox.com/artist/hybrid-theory/7af41000-0200-11db-89ca-0019b92a3933?partnerID=___",
        "Source": "Catalog"
    },
    {
        "Genres": ["More"],
        "Subgenres": ["Miscellaneous"],
        "Id": "music.A1745200-0200-11DB-89CA-0019B92A3933",
        "Name": "London Ensemble",
        "ImageUrl": "http://musicimage.xboxlive.com/content/music.A1745200-0200-11DB-89CA-0019B92A3933/image?locale=en-US",
        "Link": "http://music.xbox.com/artist/london-ensemble/a1745200-0200-11db-89ca-0019b92a3933?partnerID=___",
        "Source": "Catalog"
    }],
    "TotalItemCount": 2
},
"Albums": {
    "Items": [{
        "ReleaseDate": "2011-01-26T00:00:00Z",
        "Duration": "00:04:26",
        "TrackNumber": 15,
        "IsExplicit": false,
        "Genres": ["Electronic / Dance"],
        "Subgenres": ["Dance"],
        "Rights": ["Purchase",
        "FreeStream",
        "Stream"],
        "Subtitle": "Original Version",
        "Album": {
            "Id": "music.6147B006-0100-11DB-89CA-0019B92A3933",
            "Name": "Suite Lounge - A Luxury & Unique Collection Of Relaxing Lounge Tunes, Vol. 2",
            "ImageUrl": "http://musicimage.xboxlive.com/content/music.6147B006-0100-11DB-89CA-0019B92A3933/image?locale=en-US",
            "Link": "http://music.xbox.com/album/area-42/suite-lounge-a-luxury-unique-collection-of-relaxing-loun/6147b006-0100-11db-89ca-0019b92a3933?partnerID=___",
            "Source": "Catalog"
        },
        "Artists": [{
            "Role": "Main",
            "Artist": {
                "Id": "music.98D90600-0200-11DB-89CA-0019B92A3933",
                "Name": "Area 42",
                "ImageUrl": "http://musicimage.xboxlive.com/content/music.98D90600-0200-11DB-89CA-0019B92A3933/image?locale=en-US",
                "Link": "http://music.xbox.com/artist/area-42/98d90600-0200-11db-89ca-0019b92a3933?partnerID=___",
                "Source": "Catalog"
            }
        }],
        "Id": "music.EF46B006-0100-11DB-89CA-0019B92A3933",
        "Name": "Hybrid Theory",
        "ImageUrl": "http://musicimage.xboxlive.com/content/music.EF46B006-0100-11DB-89CA-0019B92A3933/image?locale=en-US",
        "Link": "http://music.xbox.com/track/area-42/suite-lounge-a-luxury-unique-collection-of-relaxing-loun/hybrid-theory/ef46b006-0100-11db-89ca-0019b92a3933?partnerID=___",
        "Source": "Catalog"
    },
    {
        "ReleaseDate": "2014-02-19T00:00:00Z",
        "Duration": "00:05:30",
        "TrackNumber": 2,
        "IsExplicit": false,
        "Genres": ["Electronic / Dance"],
        "Subgenres": ["Dance"],
        "Rights": ["Purchase",
        "FreeStream",
        "Stream"],
        "Album": {
            "Id": "music.99C82B08-0100-11DB-89CA-0019B92A3933",
            "Name": "The Dark",
            "ImageUrl": "http://musicimage.xboxlive.com/content/music.99C82B08-0100-11DB-89CA-0019B92A3933/image?locale=en-US",
            "Link": "http://music.xbox.com/album/hybrid-theory/the-dark/99c82b08-0100-11db-89ca-0019b92a3933?partnerID=___",
            "Source": "Catalog"
        },
        "Artists": [{
            "Role": "Main",
            "Artist": {
                "Id": "music.7AF41000-0200-11DB-89CA-0019B92A3933",
                "Name": "Hybrid Theory",
                "ImageUrl": "http://musicimage.xboxlive.com/content/music.7AF41000-0200-11DB-89CA-0019B92A3933/image?locale=en-US",
                "Link": "http://music.xbox.com/artist/hybrid-theory/7af41000-0200-11db-89ca-0019b92a3933?partnerID=___",
                "Source": "Catalog"
            }
        }],
        "Id": "music.9BC82B08-0100-11DB-89CA-0019B92A3933",
        "Name": "All Again",
        "ImageUrl": "http://musicimage.xboxlive.com/content/music.9BC82B08-0100-11DB-89CA-0019B92A3933/image?locale=en-US",
        "Link": "http://music.xbox.com/track/hybrid-theory/the-dark/all-again/9bc82b08-0100-11db-89ca-0019b92a3933?partnerID=___",
        "Source": "Catalog"
    }],
    "ContinuationToken": "___",
    "TotalItemCount": 50
}
```

}

I only have a class definition for an album and need to get a List/Array of type Album from the JSON string. However, I couldn't figure out how to do that. The class looks like this:

```
class Artist
{
    public string Name;
    List<string> genres;
    bool isExplicit;
}
```

I tried using [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) but could only parse value types and not reference types.

Comment: Json.Net should handle it fine.  One way to go if you're having problems creating your classes it so use a tool [such as this](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for not reading the documentation properly.